# Custom filter for ArrayAdapter in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, baseadapter

I want to filter `GridView`, but problem seems to be in a way I organize my data inside the `View`.

this is a code I use for layout

```
private GridView list;

private void loadListView(){
    list = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.apps_list);

    ArrayAdapter<AppDetail> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AppDetail>(this, R.layout.list_item, apps) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(apps.get(position).icon);
            appIcon.setTag(apps.get(position).name);
            TextView appLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_label);
            appLabel.setText(apps.get(position).label);
            //TextView appName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
            //appName.setText(apps.get(position).name);

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

as you might have understood, I'm filtering app list installed on the device.

now I have a search method defined in the same activity.

```
private void doMySearch(String query){

}
```

here I need to filter adapter with query. When I tried to reinitialize `arrayAdapter` and filter it with `adapter.getFilter().filter(query);`
it does not work.

What is a way to filter adapter by `apps.label` attribute?

Comment: can you show me a use case

Comment: try `class MyAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<AppDetail> {...` and override its `onBind` and `matches` methods

Comment: @pskink hey I'm very new to programming. I posted what I did with my problem. can you tell me if it wrong using this method instead of adapter filter?

Comment: so you extended my adapter,  what is your source code then?

Comment: @pskink I posted it as an answer. I did not use `class` instead I just filtered array

Comment: @pskink aaaand he is gone forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I solved my problem.
Since my filter is pretty basic I did my own loop and filtering and then passed all of this to adapter.

```
private void doMySearch(final String query){
    list = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.apps_list);


    final List<AppDetail> apps_filtered = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int q = 0; q < apps.size(); q++){
        if(apps.get(q).label.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
            Log.e("ddd", apps.get(q).label.toString().toLowerCase());

            AppDetail app = new AppDetail();
            app.label = apps.get(q).label;
            app.name = apps.get(q).name;
            app.icon = apps.get(q).icon;
            apps_filtered.add(app);
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<AppDetail> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AppDetail>(this, R.layout.list_item, apps_filtered) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(apps_filtered.get(position).icon);
            appIcon.setTag(apps_filtered.get(position).name);
            TextView appLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_label);
            appLabel.setText(apps_filtered.get(position).label);
            //TextView appName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
            //appName.setText(apps_filtered.get(position).name);

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```